# Is there any Node.js package that would allow me to mock MySql connection in order to test APIs that need db connection?

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, testing

I want to do unit testing of a few APIs written by myself, which make some queries on a **MySQL** database. But I learned recently that establishing an actual connection during testing is not a good practice and the test cases for the APIs would modify the table entries, which I don't want to happen.

I found that there is a node package called *mockgoose* which does the same thing for *MongoDB*. Is there something similar for MySQL?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the proper place to ask for a tool recommendation.

Comment: Where do you learn this ? I learn that for test case, a db of test is usefull... like a prod or dev db...

Comment: @PimentoWeb I am looking for a way to mock the queries instead of running them on the actual database. Or, should I just create a test db. I read somewhere that during testing we should not create any actual db connection or http connection. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can take a look at https://hackernoon.com/testing-node-js-in-2018-10a04dd77391 They are talking about creating a db test with some dummy values...